# Sequential loop, AngularJS Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am trying to figure out how to resolve an arbitrary number of promises one after another within a for-loop.

I have a function called *scrapePage(num)* that takes in a number and makes an HTTP call to a certain web-page. 
I have tried out a number of approaches to this problem.

1) Use an array of promises (that resolves them in random order):

```
var promises = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   promises.push(scrapPage(i));
}
$q.all(promises).then(doMoreThings);
```

2) Use a chain of calls (that is useless for an arbitrary number of calls):

```
var chain = $q.when();
chain.then(function() {
    return scrapPage(0);
}).then(function() {
    return scrapPage(1);
}).then(function() {
    return scrapPage(2);
}).then(function() {
    return scrapPage(3);
}).then(doMoreThings);
```

I was playing around with the chain function, trying to get it to work. For testing purposes, I made *scrapePage* print out "page #n" every time it resolves.

Here's what I have right now:

```
var chain = $q.when();
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log("i: " + i);
    chain = chain.then(function() {
        console.log("\ni: " + i);
        return scrapPage(i);
    });                 
}
```

I can point out two major problems it has.

First, its output is absolutely weird.

```
i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3

i: 4
page #4

i: 4
page #4

i: 4
page #4

i: 4
page #4
```

Second, I don't know how to make it *doMoreThings* after all promises are resolved.

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing **var** to **let**.

```
var chain = $q.when();
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log("i: " + i);
    chain = chain.then(function() {
        console.log("\ni: " + i);
        return scrapPage(i);
    });                 
}
```

That would probably solve the first problem.

For the second one, you could add a condition like this:

```
if (i == 4){
    doMoreThings();
}
else {
    return scrapPage(i);
}
```

instead of just `return scrapPage(i);`

Comment: Such an easy fix! Thanks a lot, it worked out perfectly.